# IF/ELSE LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, join

I need to do a LEFT JOIN with IF/ELSE, this is my query:

```
IF (M.idArtVar=null, 
    LEFT JOIN ArtMaga G 
           ON (G.idMagazzino = V.idMagazzino AND G.idArticolo = M.idArticolo), 
    LEFT JOIN ArtMaga G 
           ON (G.idMagazzino = V.idMagazzino AND G.idArticolo = M.idArticolo AND 
               G.idArtVar = M.idArtVar)
   )
```

But it doesn't work.

I also tried like this:

```
    LEFT JOIN ArtMaga AM 
           ON IF(M.idArtVar IS NULL,
                 (AM.idMagazzino = TM.idMagazzino AND AM.idArticolo = A.idArticoli),
                 (AM.idMagazzino = TM.idMagazzino AND AM.idArtVar = M.idArtVar))
```

But this query is too slow.
    How can I do?
    Thanks.

EDIT: This is full query:

```
    SELECT F.Codice AS "CodiceFornitore", F.RagioneSociale AS "RagioneSocialeFornitore", A.ArticoloFornitore, C.Descrizione AS CatDes,  S.Descrizione AS Settore, U.Sigla AS Um, U2.Sigla AS Um2, A.Moltiplicatore AS Molt, A.Collo, TM.
dMagazzino, M.idArtVar, AM.Esistenza, AM.Disponibilita,          AM.QtaImpegnata, AM.QtaOrdinata, TM.TipoSoggetto, TM.idSoggetto, ST.DataMovimento, MC.Codice, ST.Quantita, ST.Prezzo, ST.Sconti, M.idMagaRigMov

    FROM MagaRigMov M

    LEFT JOIN Articoli     A  ON A.idArticoli     = M.idArticolo
    LEFT JOIN UnMisura     U  ON U.idUnMisura     = A.idUnMisura1
    LEFT JOIN UnMisura     U2 ON U2.idUnMisura    = A.idUnMisura2 
    LEFT JOIN Iva          I  ON I.idIva          = A.idIva 
    LEFT JOIN Settori      S  ON S.idSettori      = A.idSettore 
    LEFT JOIN Fornitori    F  ON F.idFornitori    = A.idFornitore
    LEFT JOIN ArtCategorie C  ON C.idArtCategorie = A.idArtCategoria
    LEFT JOIN MagaTesMov   TM ON TM.idMagaTesMov  = M.idMagaTesMov
    LEFT JOIN STORICO      ST ON (ST.idSoggetto   = TM.idSoggetto AND ST.TipoSoggetto = TM.TipoSoggetto AND ST.idArticolo = M.idArticolo)
    LEFT JOIN MagaCausali  MC ON MC.idMagaCausali = ST.idMagaCausale
    LEFT JOIN ArtMaga      AM ON IF(M.idArtVar IS NULL,(AM.idMagazzino = TM.idMagazzino AND AM.idArticolo = A.idArticoli),
                                                       (AM.idMagazzino = TM.idMagazzino AND AM.idArtVar = M.idArtVar))
```

This query is too slow.. but works..

Comment: Can we see the full query and table definitions?

Comment: - especially the indexes? Also, do you realise that the logic behind the two expressions is different? How slow is "too slow"? How does it compare to the performance when using only one of the sets of join conditions?

Comment: Whilst the full query is interesting, it is less helpful than the structure of ArtMaga with its indexes would have been - the query will perform much faster if it is able to make use of the relevant indexes.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can't use an `IF` to make a conditional join. Because `IF` is not part of the `SELECT` syntax and even if it was (like `CASE` expressions) it wouldn't be allowed to be used like this. You can move the logic to the `ON` statement though:

```
LEFT JOIN ArtMaga G 
       ON (G.idMagazzino = V.idMagazzino AND G.idArticolo = M.idArticolo)
           AND M.idArtVar IS NULL
       OR (G.idMagazzino = V.idMagazzino AND G.idArticolo = M.idArticolo AND 
           G.idArtVar = M.idArtVar)
           AND M.idArtVar IS NOT NULL
```

which can be simplified to:

```
LEFT JOIN ArtMaga G 
       ON  (G.idMagazzino = V.idMagazzino AND G.idArticolo = M.idArticolo)
       AND (M.idArtVar IS NULL OR G.idArtVar = M.idArtVar)
```

Also notice that you can't use equality to check if an expression is null.
`M.idArtVar = null` will never be true because `NULL` can never be equal to anything (not even to `NULL`). The way to check if an expression is null is with `IS NULL`.

---

Your second query, that words, is using the `IF()` function of MySQL and seems to be correct (although I see a difference in the code with the first query, the `G.idArticolo = M.idArticolo` condition has been removed from one part.)

Why a query is slow depends on many factors and using functions on the join conditions can be one of the many. Try the change I suggest above. If it still slow, you'll have to examine the execution plan and the available indexes on the tables.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the condition in the `on` clause.  `If` is not part of a SQL statement.

```
SELECT F.Codice AS "CodiceFornitore", F.RagioneSociale AS "RagioneSocialeFornitore", 
A.ArticoloFornitore, C.Descrizione AS CatDes,  S.Descrizione AS Settore, U.Sigla AS Um, U2.Sigla AS Um2, A.Moltiplicatore AS Molt, A.Collo, TM.
dMagazzino, M.idArtVar, AM.Esistenza, AM.Disponibilita,          AM.QtaImpegnata, AM.QtaOrdinata, TM.TipoSoggetto, TM.idSoggetto, ST.DataMovimento, MC.Codice, ST.Quantita, ST.Prezzo, ST.Sconti, M.idMagaRigMov

FROM MagaRigMov M

LEFT JOIN Articoli     A  ON A.idArticoli     = M.idArticolo
LEFT JOIN UnMisura     U  ON U.idUnMisura     = A.idUnMisura1
LEFT JOIN UnMisura     U2 ON U2.idUnMisura    = A.idUnMisura2 
LEFT JOIN Iva          I  ON I.idIva          = A.idIva 
LEFT JOIN Settori      S  ON S.idSettori      = A.idSettore 
LEFT JOIN Fornitori    F  ON F.idFornitori    = A.idFornitore
LEFT JOIN ArtCategorie C  ON C.idArtCategorie = A.idArtCategoria
LEFT JOIN MagaTesMov   TM ON TM.idMagaTesMov  = M.idMagaTesMov
LEFT JOIN STORICO      ST ON (ST.idSoggetto   = TM.idSoggetto AND ST.TipoSoggetto = TM.TipoSoggetto AND ST.idArticolo = M.idArticolo)
LEFT JOIN MagaCausali  MC ON MC.idMagaCausali = ST.idMagaCausale
LEFT JOIN ArtMaga      AM ON (AM.idMagazzino = TM.idMagazzino AND (m.idartVar is NULL and AM.idArtVar = M.idArtVar or AM.idArticolo = A.idArticoli))
```